# res.location double encodes url query strings

Tags: python, falcon, falconframework

I've passed a URL to res.location which has another URL as a query string, and when the res.location is set in the header, the URL in the query string is encoded twice.

For example,
URL passed to res.location is,

```
res.location = 'http://localhost?redirect_uri=http://somepage'
```

Expected Header:
**Location**: http://localhost?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsomepage

Actual Header:
**Location**: http://localhost?redirect_uri=http%253A%252F%252Fsomepage

Any suggestion to fix this issue is welcomed. Thank you

Comment: Try to open a bug. The workaround is http://falcon.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Response.set_headers

Comment: https://github.com/falconry/falcon/blob/296e6430c505e369ecf620404b28287395369385/falcon/response_helpers.py#L16